# Задача на декораторы

Tags: python, декоратор

Задача звучит так:

Создайте функцию-декоратор **time_decorator**, которая должна вычислить время выполнения декорированной функции и поместить это значение времени в словарь **execution_time**, где ключом является имя декорированной функции. Значением является время выполнения этой функции.
Например:

```
@time_decorator
def func_add(a, b):
    sleep(0.2)
    return a + b

>>> func_add(10, 20)
30

>>> execution_time['func_add']
0.212341254
```

Мой код:

```
from typing import Dict
import time

execution_time: Dict[str, float] = {}


def time_decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(a, b, sleep_time):
        global execution_time
        start = time.time()
        fn(a, b, sleep_time)
        end = time.time()
        x = end - start
        execution_time = {fn.__name__: x}
        return execution_time

    return wrapper


@time_decorator
def func_add(a, b, sleep_time):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(a + b)
```

Результат:

```
sleep_time = 0.1
func_add(10, 20, sleep_time)
print(execution_time['func_add'])

30
0.1009986400604248
```

Не понимаю, почему время сна в примере задано как **sleep(0.2)**. И в моем коде строка **execution_time['func_add']** без функции **print** не даст никакого результата.
Тест выдал следующую ошибку:

```
Test name: test_f1_time_decorator
Failure message:
def test_f1_time_decorator():
        sleep_time = TIME_100MS
>       assert 30 == task.time_decorator(func_test1)(10, 20, sleep_time)
E       AssertionError: assert 30 == {'func_test1': 0.10023021697998047}
E        +  where {'func_test1': 0.10023021697998047} = <function time_decorator.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fa5049536d0>(10, 20, 0.1)
E        +    where <function time_decorator.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fa5049536d0> = <function time_decorator at 0x7fa504a10f70>(func_test1)
E        +      where <function time_decorator at 0x7fa504a10f70> = task.time_decorator

tests/test_task.py:14: AssertionError
```

Comment: Функция внутри декоратора возращает глобальный словарь. А должна возвращать результат оборачиваемой функции. Тест об этом и говорит.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так, вроде сработало:

```py
from typing import Dict
import time

execution_time: Dict[str, float] = {}


def time_decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global execution_time
        time1 = time.time()
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        time2 = time.time()
        time3 = time2 - time1
        execution_time[fn.__name__] = time3
        return result

    return wrapper
```